# convert List ot String with point separator to Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, hashmap, converters, separator, mapper

Looking for a beautiful solution on Java, and it will be helpful for me. Thanks in advance for any advise.
There are list of strings with comma separators:

```
"a.b.cc"
"a.dd"
"a.b.f.gg"
"u.ww"
```

and I have values for the last elements in each row

```
cc -> 1, dd -> 5, gg -> 8, ww ->60
```

And as a result I should have Map<Sting,Object>

This result I can describe in json: `{"a":{"b":{"cc":1,"f":{"gg":8}}"dd":5}"u":60}`
So the task is to convert strings with separators to map with predefined values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static Map<String, Object> convert(List<String> list, Map<String, Integer> map) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new TreeMap<>();
    for (String s : list) {
        String[] f = s.split("\\.");
        Map<String, Object> t = result;
        int i = 0;
        for (int m = f.length - 1; i < m; ++i)
            t = (Map<String, Object>)t.computeIfAbsent(
                f[i], k -> new TreeMap<>());
        t.put(f[i], map.get(f[i]));
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of(
        "a.b.cc",
        "a.dd",
        "a.b.f.gg",
        "u.ww");
    Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of(
        "cc", 1, "dd", 5, "gg", 8, "ww", 60);

    Map<String, Object> result = convert(list, map);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

output:

```
{a={b={cc=1, f={gg=8}}, dd=5}, u={ww=60}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Work for me very very well.